# How can we plot a step function in Mathematica and make it periodic?

Tags: plotting, periodic-function

Consider a periodic function of the form

$$
f(t) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{r}
1, & 0\leq t \leq T/2, \\ 
0, & T/2\leq t\leq T, \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

with $f(t+T)=f(t)$. How can we define this function in Mathematica? How can we make a plot of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an starting point, `SquareWave[{0, 1}, x/Pi]` will give you a periodic function with values 1 or 0, with period $\pi$. You can plot is as follows:

```
Plot[
  SquareWave[{0, 1}, x/Pi],
  {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
  GridLines -> {Range[-2 Pi, 2 Pi, Pi/2]}
]
```

[image: plot of the above square wave with gridlines at Pi/2]

It seems to me that you simply have a function varying with a period T/2 in your requirements.